# Is UAT(User Acceptance Testing) same as Compliance Testing?

Tags: testing, user-acceptance-testing

Defn: What is compliance testing?  Its basically an audit of a system carried out against a known criterion.

Based on this defn, can UAT be termed as Compliance Testing, since UAT is confirmation of product on basis of SRS?

Answer (score 1):

Both terms are very similar.
To distinguish them, I would say that:

- Compliance Testing would better suit in a regulated environment with policies or standards. It sounds more like "did we apply the rule?"
- UAT is user oriented. Here it not about rules but about wishes of a customer. So sounds more like "did we produce what was expected?"